# How can I use Sessions and Auth cross controller?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I have two controllers that need to communicate OrdersController and UsersController, because when a new user places an order I process a register form on the order that i send to UsersController::register().

My register action uses Auth to log in the user after the basket is processed but it returns **Fatal error: Call to a member function login() on a non-object**:

```
//UsersController::register($data = null)
if(!empty($data))
  $this->request->data['User'] = $data;

if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
  $registeredUser = $this->User->read(null, $this->User->id);
  if ($this->Auth->login($registeredUser['User']))
    if (empty($data))
       $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
    else
       return $this->User->id;
}
```

I use this action on the normal registration page and also for other apis like Google or Facebook inside the UsersController calling it with **$this->register($data)** and it workes fine. But when I use it in the OrdersController like:

```
//UsersController::__construct()
public function __construct($request = null, $response = null, $session = null) {
    parent::__construct($request, $response);
    if (isset($session))
        $this->Session = $session;
}
```

I had to override __construct because I had the same problem with setFlash()

```
//OrdersController::add();
$newUser = new UsersController(null, null, $this->Session);
$newUserId = $newUser->register($data['User']);
```

Comment: have you used `Auth` & `Session` components in your controller

Comment: I am loading them in AppController as they extend it, but I also loaded the components in the controller to test it. Still got the same problem. The user is getting written in the DB but I still get this error: Call to a member function login() on a non-object

Comment: can you put your whole controller code here

Comment: I found a solution. I realised that i already needed the UsersController::register($data) to return the last User->id so I can continue processing of the order so I conditioned the Auth login if $data is empty, meaning that it will autologin only for direct usage of actions. When it is called cross-controller it returns the id, and I will make the autologin in Orders. I also made an autoLogin action in appController usable in all controllers